# Joke or taunt/bully?

Tags: professionalism, new-job

I was made redundant from my last job and had been jobless for 4 months, now I joined a work place as a senior and I feel like I m not fit for the position because of 3 reason.

1. My knowledge is all rusty and I struggle (I m slow),
2. I am having hard time understanding the work (so does the guys who been working for a year coz old developer left and no one know how things work)
3. During today pairing programming, as pointed in point 1 my knowledge is rusty and some I do not know, the guy who was pairing with me, saying "Ok you passed as a junior developer" and when asked about something he mentioned "do you want me to feed you like a baby".

Yes I agree I am very is some skillset, I am not a native british or english speaker but should I taking this sort of attitude from my a developer who has a bit of character? He kind of a person who smiles when he want to when saying hi or just not even smile or say hello?

I am not sure if he is Joking or mocking/bullying me because it is not even a month for me working here. I have a 121 coming up, should I bring it with up with my manager or be more compose.

My weakness is that a junior dev knows more than me hence I feel not fit for position and given what I mentioned, I am not regarded as senior?

Comment: Your knowledge is rusty after 4 months? or is this a different area from that you were in previously?

Comment: @Smock both, my last job was heavy on UX and now it is heavy on UI.

Comment: "my last job was heavy on UX and now it is heavy on UI" That's a strange statement if you are a programmer. Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @DJClayworth I am a web developer, a part of my job is to design and do coding as well, a different job, different task.. In my last one, I was mostly on cosmetics side of things like CSS and now I m less on CSS and more towards JS, so 6 months of last job and 4 months redudancy made me rusty

Comment: More a side note: If you feel self-doubt because the junior is technologically ahead of you, consider this: The moment the junior made that comment he failed the senior test. Because being a senior in rank is about more than knowing your technological niche, it's also about being professional and support the team. Some juniors know their particular technological area more or less well and that can get them cocky - especially when they feel they have a chance to feel "superior" to someone that others see as more experienced/superior in rank.

Answer (score 9):

You're not a junior developer.  You're simply new to the company and still learning how things work there.

Bring up your lack of knowledge in this domain with your supervisor.  Ask for additional training to understand what it is you're going to be doing there a bit better.  There may be documentation or other materials you didn't know about.

I'd bring up that the junior developer is acting inappropriately towards you as a separate discussion.  Your one-on-one meeting should focus on you, your performance, and how you can get better.

Comment: There is no documentation, one thing more I noticed that a task assigned to me and another fellow was done by that junior dev. I came to know about it in sprint meeting when I said that I am about to finish that work. There is a deadline looming for the dev but I am sort of confused to stay or look for another work as getting laid off (which I had been in past ) look bad on CV e.g "why did u work at X company for 1 month"? I agree I m weak in what job demands of me. I asked recruiter to ask my manager n from his talk, he seem impressed though I haven't done anything, but to lend help to team

Comment: Be direct with your manager then.  If your manager assigned you work, and the junior dev did it without being prompted, bring it up that the junior dev is not respecting other's assigned tasks.  The issue sounds like you have one person that knows what they're doing and it is bringing you down.  The only way to resolve that is to try and learn.

Comment: I feel like the junior statement was referring to tech stack knowledge more than domain knowledge.

Comment: This is a good answer. To be honest, just from the little you’ve written here, the junior doesn’t seem like a great person to work with. You would be surprised at how important it is to be a good employee and co-worker and your manager is probably happy to have you on board to offset the juniors bad attitude.

Answer (score 0):

Don't allow your lack of knowledge as a tools for other to make fun of you.
No one knows everything and no one was born with all the experience.

Try putting 1 hr extra after office daily for 30 days to brush up skills add new certification and new skills, help other in your team but try to keep your knowledge to yourself (don't show off that you brushed up your skills or learned new ones).
Don't help until asked and learn to say no sometimes. 
Also , prioritize your work, don't get involved in all the things , start with small and easy ones in your new project where everyone seems to second guessing.

Do not bring up that colleague in 121 discussion it will be looked as complaint rather than bully. You have to plan to counter that bully in front of everyone tell him to talk nicely once. If this goes on drop a mail to your HR and this matter should be looked by them.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

> and when asked about something he mentioned "do you want me to feed you like a baby"

The main question here is, did you ask about something that's specific for the company and/or for the project - that is, something that they cannot reasonably expect you to google for, or to find it on stack overflow or somewhere...

...or did you ask about something, that's not company-specific but general software development or a specific but public technology (for example, html, Angular, SQL, whatever), because in this case, if you're a senior developer, you're expected to be able to find documentation and tutorials and go through them on your own.

In the first case, you were in the right to ask, and his answer wasn't good or polite.

In the second case, when people ask stuff which they could have looked up online on their own, "do you want me to feed you like a baby" would be applicable.
Well, you can still ask once or twice, it might be faster to do it than google for it... but if you keep asking and asking, at some point you're wasting the other person's time for something you can (and, therefore, should) do on your own.

A senior developer doesn't necessarily know all there is, or any given technology, but is capable of learning it on his own when needed.

Comment: I asked what conventions they follows as he was pointing out like "u don't know this? Have u ever worked on this? how do u manage?" I felt like he was senior asking me junior questions. There are no docs n everyone is headless chicken n I feel like I m just wasting time as they even interview another senior n never told me or share n I feel insecure that I might get booted as I had previously coz company wanted fast, quick n I was trying to get hold of situation so I have mixed feeling. I get anxiety attack and cannot do my work if I get anxiety attack coz ppl like him make me feel poor.

Comment: "do you want me to feed you like a baby" is rude, even if it might be applicable.

Comment: How might that ever be applicable in the workplace?